# Converting unix date-timestamp to time for a particular timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert unix timestamp to time for a particular timezone.

say for example unix time stamp is - 1446960600
I want to convert this timestamp to America/Los Angeles ?

Comment: your question is no clear ? can you tell which format actually you need

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a unix timestamp integer into a Javascript date like this

```
var date = new Date(1446960600 * 1000);
```

Unix timestamps are in the UTC timezone, but there isn't an easy way to do timezone changes in Javascript.

I recommend you use a time library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/). It handles edge cases like daylight savings that you would have to take into account if you do it yourself.

Here's some sample code from another answer:

```
function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
     var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
     return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18612568/1031569

You can use the `getTimezoneOffset()` method of a DateTime to calculate the timezone change, but understand this won't take into account daylights saving or leap year changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use momentjs. You can choose your format  and you just set the country you need

http://momentjs.com/